# Python/Selenium - Cant click' Accept cookies' button on www.instagram.com

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to login on instagram using python selenium. But i have to Accept the cookies in order to continue.

[image: 1]

This is my code

```
class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        sleep(2)
 #this is the code that im trying to use, so to click the accept button 
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]").click() 
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
            .send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
            .send_keys(pw)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log in')]")\
            .click()
        sleep(4)
```

The problem is that when it gets to click the accept button it does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Should click the accept the login and the next two elements after it. Just wait till the element becomes clickable and then click it.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept']"))).click()
#Your code
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button"))).click()  
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Save Info']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Turn On']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept']").click()
```

I posted my solution here: [Accepting cookies error with Python/Selenium on www.instagram.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847101/accepting-cookies-error-with-python-selenium-on-www-instagram-com/65060778#65060778)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver

alert=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Accept All")]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by selecting the button with the corresponding text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cookie_button = WebDriverWait(wd,15).until(
                       EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                              (By.XPATH,
                               "//button[text()='Accept all cookies']")))
cookie_button.click()
```