# Accepting cookies error with Python/Selenium on www.instagram.com

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to, using Firefox, log into Instagram by using Python Selenium using the following code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
sleep(2)

username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

username_input.send_keys("<your username>")
password_input.send_keys("<your password>")

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

Everytime I run it, it correctly opens a new web browser window, fills in the username and password entries but, in the end, I get the following error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="submit"> is not clickable at point (844,327) because another element <div class="piCib"> obscures it
```

I think it is due to the fact that there is a cookies acceptance pop-up that my code above is not dealing with. A screenshot with the automatically filled in username and password fields can be seen below. Does anyone know how to accept these cookies automatically?

P.S. I have tried the answer in [Python/Selenium - Cant click' Accept cookies' button on www.instagram.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64271467/python-selenium-cant-click-accept-cookies-button-on-www-instagram-com), but with no luck.

[image: Cookies-PopUp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on this too and had a bit of struggle.
This command finds the "Accept" button on the cookies pop up:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept']")
```

After the log in it prompts 2 more pop ups: 1 to save the log in informations, 1 to allow notifications on the browser. The lines after "#not now" take care of them in the same manner

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(2)
# cookie 
cookie_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept']")
cookie_button.click()

username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

username_input.send_keys("<your username>")
password_input.send_keys("<your password>")

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

sleep(3)
# not now
save_login_info_button= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']")
save_login_info_button.click()
sleep(3)
notification_button= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']")
notification_button.click()

browser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution partially works! I say partially because when launching the previous code I still get an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="submit"> is not clickable at point (842,296) because another element <div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt      MMzan   _0PwGv         uL8Hv     l4b0S    "> obscures it`

Comment: Well, I was able to solve the issue simply by adding another sleep before clicking the login button. Thanks for sharing the solution.